# Difference bettween TranslateX, LayoutX and ScaleX in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

There seems many coordinate systems in JavaFx. In [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class, there are `getTranslateX`, `getLayoutX` and `getScaleX` to get X position. In [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) class, there are `getX` and `getSceneX` to get X position. What's difference between them? I am so confused.

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html There is no `getTranslateX()` method in `MouseEvent`.

Comment: I linked a document that explains it.

Comment: @James_D I have read this doc a few days ago, but I do not understand it very well. Perhaps it it easy understand for you, but not for green hands.

Comment: Well, not sure how anyone else can really help. “I don’t understand “ isn’t actually a question. What successful programmers do when they don’t understand something is write some code, test some things out, and see what the methods return under different circumstances. No one else can understand the documentation for you (though they can answer specific questions if you ask them).

Comment: @James_D You are right, but if one can find understandable explain in forum, who write demo? It the problem of efficiency. In addition, always let person read doc is not friendly to green hands(this is why stackoverflow exists), 
if this continues, less people will learn JavaFx in the future. So I answer my question myself for other green hand.

Comment: `MouseEvent#getX()` returns the x-coordinate relative to the source node. `MouseEvent#getSceneX()` returns the x-coordinate relative to the source node's _scene_. And `MouseEvent#getScreenX()` returns the x-coordinate relative to the entire _screen_.

Answer (score 2):

- layout coordinate: coordinate defined by parent layout (relative to parent layout)
- translate coordinate: offset to layout coordinate

I write a [interactive demo](https://github.com/DQinYuan/coordinatefx) to demonstrate it:

[image]

About ScaleX, it is just not related to position, it is for stretch.